# Swashbuckle generates schemas for internal c# classes

Tags: c#, swashbuckle, system.text.json

When using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` (version 6.3.1) with System.text.json, the schemas generate a bunch of internals from c#, like a schema for `Assembly`, `ConstructorInfo`, and others.

I think this happens when I've created an endpoint that returns an interface (possibly). Not entirely sure. If I utilize the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft` package for generating the swagger documentation it isn't a problem - these schemas are not generated. I'd however like to not have a dependency on newtonsoft for the sole reason of getting the valid schemas.

It's not a huge issue, however it is a bit annoying that our openapi/swagger docs have irrelevant information. I'd love to get around that.

Is this a known bug? Is there a way around it? Any help would be much appreciated.

I've tried to search for different combinations of the problem, but with no success. My querying skills my be bad, so if this question has already been asked, then I am truly sorry.

[image: image of schemas that contain both Assembly, CallingConventions and ContructorInfo]

EDIT:
The bug seems to be due to the fact that we have a value type that we expose in the API with a custom serializer. that object has a `Type` property, however, this is never actually exposed in the API due to the serializer - (which we also registered with Swashbuckle, so it isn't actually exposed in the Swashbuckle documentation, however, I assume Swashbuckle already added the objects to the schema prior to us registering the "correct" serializer.)

Comment: You could add a self-written `IDocumentProcessor`, `ISchemaProcessor` and / or an OperationFilter. In a first step simply *do nothing*. But you can set a breakpoint end check why this data comes in.
Another approach would be reading the raw *swagger.json* with a text editor and check where these types are used. Maybe this gives you a clue where it comes from.

Answer (score 2):

One way to remove it is by an `IDocumentFilter` like this:

```
    public class RemoveSchemasFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
        {
            var types = (Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType())).GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsClass).Select(x => x.Name);

            IDictionary<string, OpenApiSchema> _remove = swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Where(x => !types.Contains(x.Key)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, OpenApiSchema> _item in _remove)
            {
                swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Remove(_item.Key);
            }
        }
    }
```

in you DI where you register swagger just add this

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.DocumentFilter<RemoveSchemasFilter>())
```

Comment: As I currently have about 35 "wrong" schemas, this would be a bit cumbersome, tightly coupled to the exact set of "wrong" schemas, and won't be a long-term solution. It might simply be a bug in Swashbuckle. Not sure.

Comment: @CasperBang I've updated the code. Can you please report back about it. It is hard to work for an issue you can't even produce :(

Comment: I'll give it a spin tomorrow or the day after, and create a minimal git repo that reproduces the error - sorry for not providing a better report ;)

Comment: did it work?(word limit)

Comment: I had difficulties replicating it in a project without proprietary packages that we have in our project. sorry about that. I've updated the issue above with more related info. It seems very much to be a bug, so I'll replicate it in fullness and support a bug report to swashbuckle.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this question because I had the same problem. In my case, the issue was caused by specifying a `FileNotFoundException` as the `ResponseType`:

```cs
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FileNotFoundException), StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
```

After I created my own `FileNotFoundResponse` class:

```cs
public class DocumentNotFoundResponse
{
    public required string Message { get; init; }
    public required string FileName { get; init; }
}
```

and specified it as `ResponseType`, the internal .NET classes were no longer displayed as schema:

```cs
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(DocumentNotFoundResponse), StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
```

This behavior probably occurs with other internal types as well. However, I have not tested this.

So I don't know if it solves the OP's problem, but maybe it will help someone.

Comment: It's a valid perspective, never the less. it being some time ago, I cannot remember the exact case, and am no longer on that specific project, but it was non-trivial removing all related types, however it is a good point about narrowing down what generates the specific types.